# Looking for jQuery addon for product display

Tags: jquery, plugins, gallery

I'm currently designing a portfolio website and I'm looking for some jQuery addon that would be helpful to display all products made by the company.

Any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly  , Your question is quite vague when you say "display products"

Comment: The user was just looking for some jQuery plugins to display products or images. I made a few suggestions below. Seems that was what he was looking for :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for some neat ways to display images (or products) check these plugins out.

(I've used them all in the past for various projects)

- http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/
- http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
- http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/
- http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Here are a few other links:

- http://mattbango.com/demos/hover-zoom/
- http://jquery.malsup.com/hoverpulse/
- http://www.pikachoose.com/

Hope this helps :)